# Limit URL query length?

Tags: php, url

So I've got a PHP-based site that's running on Apache.  The URL's of the pages I'm talking about look like this:
http://www.example.com/?task=0&fw=FW_1W9AigHcAzgtjhBNc6W1QW
The long string for `fw` is randomly generated.  Starting from `?fw=FW_1W...`, it's always 36 characters long.  If someone adds anything to this, a major malfunction occurs and does some permanent damage (weird situation, I know...).  What I'm looking to do is make my PHP script ignore everything after a certain number of characters in the URL.  Or perhaps ignore everything after 25 characters for `$fw`?  I barely understand programming but I feel like this should be possible... Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What an odd setup... but sure you can:

```
$fwstring = substr($_GET['fw'],0,25);   //get 25 chars from index 0 of $_GET['fw']
```

Answer (score 2):

Keep bad requests away from your script:

```
<?php
if (strlen($_GET['fw'])!=36) {
    header("Status: 400 Bad Request", true, 400); 
    exit();
}
// your code ...
```